# One time redirect

Tags: javascript, html, css, redirect

Is there a way to do a one time redirect? Where it goes to an entrance page, and says enter site, then you go to the index.html page.

the best example of what I'm trying to accomplish: www.matisyahuworld.com

There's a page order.html that's the first page you see before you can go to the index.html page

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would have to check if the user is new or not. The only way I know how to do that is to use `javascript` cookies :)

```
document.cookie = 'unique_user = second time visitor; 
                   expires = date you want; path=/'
```

Of course everything is made easier with `jQuery`:

```
$.cookie("example", "foo");
```

The logic would be, check if your `cookie` exists within the clients browser, if it does, don't put up splash page and redirect straight to `index.html`. If there is no `cookie` send it to splash, `splash.html`, and set the `cookie` there.

Here is a great resource on how to do that:
[Javascript Cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)

Answer (score 0):

*setcookie* is more simple to use:

```
$expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
setcookie(user,visited, $expire);
if(isset($_COOKIE["user"]))
{
    RedirectToURL("index.html");
}
```

*To create function RedirectToURL*

```
function RedirectToURL($url)
{
    header("Location: $url");
    exit;
}
```

**NOTE :** Above code can be used for PHP scripting.Yet it is simple .Just add the above lines in

```
<?PHP
```

and end with

```
?>
```

also you must save the file with .php extension